# C++ program in VSCode on Windows compiles and runs without output - What could be the issue?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc

I'm facing an issue with a C++ program in Visual Studio Code on my Windows machine. When I compile and run the program, it completes without any errors or output. To make things more confusing, when I run the exact same program in an [online C++ compiler](https://www.online-cpp.com/), it works as expected and displays the output correctly.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Other functions like `printf` seem to work fine on VSCode and give output.

I'd appreciate any insights into what might be causing this behavior and how I can ensure that the expected output is displayed when running the program in VSCode on Windows.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could have crashed because of [Dll Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell). Could be that you have a problem with your compiler setup. Did you follow the official VSCode instructions and use msys2 to install MinGW? [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) Could be other problems like your antivirus.

Comment: Yes, i did follow those [instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) and used MSYS2.

Comment: One basic thing is to run the executable directly from a console window. That eliminates (or indicates) certain problems with the IDE.

Comment: I would say test it from the `C:\msys64\mingw64.exe` or `C:\msys64\ucrt64.exe` terminals.  The latter one is if you used the ucrt MinGW from msys2. If it works correctly in the terminal you may want to investigate other instances of the MinGW runtime (libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
libstdc++6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll) in the folders of your PATH environment variable.

Comment: In regards to all these suggestions, I have tried to run it from cmd.exe, and still same problem, no output. Sadly, same for `C:\msys64\mingw64.exe` and `C:\msys64\ucrt64.exe`.

Comment: 1) How exactly are you running the program? C/C++ extension launch config? C/C++ extension's run button? Code Runner's run button? 2) Where are you looking for the output? Output Panel? Debug console? Integrated terminal? 3) Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.